# Password Checking/ Strengthening Password

Tags: javascript, html, regex, password-strength

I'm trying to create an account for a user and I want to strengthen the password, what should I add?

I don't know to strengthen the password, by this I meant that I want to require Upper case and lower case as well as adding numbers to a password.

am I missing something? or something is wrong here? Should I change everything here?

```
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-12 col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right">Username</label>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-6">
  <input data-parsley-type="alphanum" type="text" name="username" pattern="(?=.*[a-z]).{10, }.+" required="" placeholder="" class="for m-control">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-12 col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right" for="pass1">Password</label>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-6">
  <input  data-parsley-type="alphanum" type="passwrd" id="password" name="password"  required="" placeholder="" class="form-control" onkeyup="return validate()">
    <ul>
        <li id="uppercase">At least 1 Uppercase Character</li>
        <li id="lowercase">At least 1 Lowercase Character</li>
        <li id="num">At least 1 Number</li>
        <li id="maxChar">At least 8 characters long</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

tried this for the js I think I messed everything up here since it is not working

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            var lowercase = new RegExp('[a-z]');
            var uppercase = new RegExp('[A-Z]');
            var number = new RegExp('[0-9]');
            $("#password").keyup(function(){
                var password = $(this).val()
                    if(password.length == 8){
                        $("maxChar").css("color", "green");
                    }else{
                        $("maxChar").css("color", "red");
                    }
                    if(password.match(lowercase)){
                        $(".lowercase").css("color", "green");
                    }else{
                        $(".lowercase").css("color", "red");
                    }
                    if(password.match(uppercase)){
                        $(".uppercase").css("color", "green");
                    }else{
                        $(".uppercase").css("color", "red");
                    }
                    if(password.match(number)){
                        $(".num").css("color", "green");
                    }else{
                        $(".num").css("color", "red");
                    }
                    if (/^[a-zA-Z0-9]=$/.test(password) == false){

                    }   $(".symbol").css("color", "green");
                    }else{
                        $(".symbol").css("color", "red");
                    }
            })
    </script>-->
```

Comment: You probably don't want to force the password length to be exactly 8 characters

Comment: What is meant with `[a-zA-Z0-9]=`? That would be a single letter or number and an equal sign.

Comment: "*I think I messed everything up"* - Why do you think that?  What actual problem are you observing?  *"it is not working"* - What is "not working" about it?  Are you getting an error?  An unexpected result?  Something else?  When you step through the code in a debugger, which specific operation produces an unexpected result?

Comment: [Mandatory comic](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Comment: I've seen on other sites that you can style those requirements as a checkbox, then in your keyUp function, check which of the requirements are accomplished and mark them as completed. Only let the user submit once all of the requirements are completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are issues with your code:

- it produces syntax error: excess `{`, and missing `})`
- the referenced elements are off: class vs id
- logical error: test for `>=`
- regex error for symbol
- `onkeyup=""` not needed when using jQuery

Fixed code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#password").keyup(function() {
    var password = $(this).val();
    if(password.length >= 8){
      $("#maxChar").css("color", "green");
    } else {
      $("#maxChar").css("color", "red");
    }
    if(/[a-z]/.test(password)) {
      $("#lowercase").css("color", "green");
    } else {
      $("#lowercase").css("color", "red");
    }
    if(/[A-Z]/.test(password)) {
      $("#uppercase").css("color", "green");
    } else {
      $("#uppercase").css("color", "red");
    }
    if(/[0-9]/.test(password)) {
      $("#num").css("color", "green");
    } else {
      $("#num").css("color", "red");
    }
    if(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/.test(password)) {
      $("#symbol").css("color", "green");
    } else {
      $("#symbol").css("color", "red");
    }
  }).trigger('keyup');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-12 col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right">Username</label>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-6">
  <input data-parsley-type="alphanum" type="text" name="username" pattern="(?=.*[a-z]).{10, }.+" required="" placeholder="" class="for m-control" />
   </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-12 col-sm-3 col-form-label text-sm-right" for="pass1">Password</label>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-8 col-lg-6">
  <input  data-parsley-type="alphanum" type="password" id="password" name="password"  required="" placeholder="" class="form-control" />
    <ul>
        <li id="uppercase">At least 1 Uppercase Character</li>
        <li id="lowercase">At least 1 Lowercase Character</li>
        <li id="symbol">At least 1 Symbol</li>
        <li id="num">At least 1 Number</li>
        <li id="maxChar">At least 8 characters long</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I still have one problem, why does it still proceeds in creating the username and password even when I only put 1 character in it? although it does checks the 8 characters long at least.

Comment: You'd need to set a flag if any check fails, and if so disable the form submit button

Comment: here's my submit button is something missing here?

`<div class="form-group row text-right">
<div class="col col-sm-10 col-lg-9 offset-sm-1 offset-lg-0"> 
<button class="btn btn-space btn-success btn-primary">Submit</button> 
</div>`

Comment: Add an ID to the button such as `id="registerButton"`, set a `weakPasswordFlag` variable in the `.keyup()` function, and at the end of you `.keyup()` function enable/disable the button based on that flag: `$('#registerButton').prop('disabled', weakPasswordFlag);`